# How to remove possibility to change focus from embedded flash

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flash

I have an `embedded flash` on my site. But sometimes I need to overlay it with `DIV`. My problem is when user accidentaly clicks into that `DIV`, focus from flash will be removed. I do not have access to that flash.

Is there any solution to totally remove possibility to change focus from flash?

I tried remove events with javascript from `DIV`, but once javascript from site is interpreted, focus from flash is removed.

Thank you!

**UPDATE:**

Flash is embedded in an `IFRAME` from another domain, so Cross-origin policy will not allow me to change focus back to flash if it is once removed.

Answer (score 0):

Put the iframe in the id `flashid`

```
   $('body').click(function(){
      $('#flashid').focus()
    });
```

Comment: Put the iframe in a DIV with id `flashid`

Comment: that will set focus just on iframe, not into embedded flash. If i will use iframe content and there find an element with certain id like `#embedded_flash`, that will still not working due cross-origin policy

Comment: if you wan to manupulate the dom element inside the cross domain iframe is not possible , but you can when you have control on both domain